# Is there really no bulk insert in the AppFabric Cache 1.1 API?

Tags: windows-server, appfabric-cache

I'm looking at the API and I don't see any way to send a collection of *individual* objects to cache at the same time.

Given that latency can be a significant issue wouldn't bulk insert afford the possibility of huge performance gains under certain circumstances?

I sure hope I'm missing something; this is probably a deal breaker for us since we need to initialize our cache with large amounts of data at system start and time is precious.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about bulk operations giving a performance boost since the usual insert, add, remove methods work with single key-value pairs, while the bulk operations let you work with a collection of key-value pairs. The idea behind bulk operations is to minimize the cluster traffic by bundling multiple operations into a single call. This is handy if you want to work with collection of items. I don't think appfabric provides for this. You an try NCache , which comes with bulk operations and also provides for bulk operations at the cluster level on startup:

http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/